# Will reinstalling GRUB reinstall a boot-loader in my MBR?

Tags: boot, partitioning, boot-repair, mbr

I had 7 partitions for a dual boot Win7 / Ubuntu18.04:

- sda1: Microsoft stuff
- sda2: Microsoft stuff
- sda3: Microsoft stuff
- sda4: /boot
- sda5: /
- sda6: /home
- sda7: swap

I deleted my windows and turned it into a data partition. What I actually did was to simply delete sda 1, 2 and 3 partitions, and create a new sda1 partition. And now I can't boot on this hard drive.

I tried to use *boot-repair-disk* (on a live USB) to diagnostic/fix my boot. And [here is the report](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mVpv8n7Pnb/).

As far as I understand it, my GRUB itself is okay, but I lost my MBR. But *boot-repair-disk* won't propose me to fix sda's MDR, all I can do is to fix GRUB (with proposed options looking like: "separate /boot: sda4" and "boot to: sda5").

Will applying *boot-repair-disk*'s recommended GRUB repair fix my MDR problem? Is there any risk that it would alter my sda5 and/or sda6 partitions?

Comment: your report is not accessible without password. Please paste it to https://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Oh, damn! My mistake. I edited my post with a correct link.

Comment: You have a gpt partitioned drive, so Windows had to be UEFI. And Ubuntu's fstab shows mount of ESP - EFI system partition. But you also then must have erased the ESP which was a FAT32 formatted partition with boot flag. Add a new ESP with gparted, and boot Boot-Repair in UEFI boot mode. Then it should offer to reinstall grub in UEFI mode. Your sda1 was both Microsoft & Ubuntu's ESP.

Comment: Looks like oldfred is correct. You will also have to update `/etc/fstab` to the UUID of the new ESP.